# Python dir command to determine the methods

Tags: python, api, documentation, wxpython

I am using Python's `dir()` function to determine what attributes and methods a class has.

For example to determine the methods in `wx.Frame`, I use `dir(wx.Frame)`

Is there any command to determine the list of arguments for each method? For example, if I want to know what arguments belong to `wx.Frame.CreateToolBar()`.

Comment: Are you talking about *argument/parameters*? Otherwise, your question does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: Try using `help`. `help(wx.Frame.CreateToolBar)` for instance, will show you the signature needed to call the method

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `help(fun)` to enter the help editor with the function's signature and docstring. You can also simply use `print fun.__doc__` and for most mature libraries you should get reasonable documentation about the parameters and the function signature.

If you're talking about interactive help, consider using [IPython](http://ipython.org/) which has some useful extras. For instance you could type `%psource fun` to get a printout of the source code for the function `fun`, and with tab completion you could just type `wx.Frame.` and then hit TAB to see a list of all of the methods and attributes available within `wx.Frame`.

Answer (score 1):

Even though GP89 seems to have already answered this question, I thought I'd jump in with a little more detail.

First, GP89's suggestion was the use Python's built-in [`help()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#help). This is a method you can use in the interactive console. For methods, it will print the method's declaration line along with the class' [docstring](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), if it is defined. You can also access this with `<object>.__doc__` For example:

```
>>> def testHelp(arg1, arg2=0):
...    """This is the docstring that will print when you
...    call help(testHelp). testHelp.__doc__ will also
...    return this string. Here is where you should
...    describe your method and all its arguments."""
...
>>> help(testHelp)
Help on function testHelp in module __main__:

testHelp(arg1, arg2=0)
    This is the docstring that will print when you
    call help(testHelp). testHelp.__doc__ will also
    return this string. Here is where you should
    describe your method and all its arguments.
>>>
```

However, another extremely important tool for understanding methods, classes and functions is the toolkit's API. For built-in Python functions, you should check the [Python Doc Library](http://docs.python.org/library/index.html). That's where I found the documentation for the `help()` function. You're using wxPython, whose API can be found [here](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/), so a quick search for "wx.Frame api" and you can find [this page describing all of `wx.Frame`'s methods and variables.](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Frame-class.html) Unfortunately, `CreatteToolBar()` isn't particularly well documented but you can still see it's arguments:

> CreateToolBar(self, style, winid, name)

Happy coding!